# React component single instance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, singleton

I have a counter component created by [this](https://github.com/ndresx/react-countdown) npm package.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Theme, createStyles, withStyles, WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import withRoot from '../../../withRoot';
import Countdown, { CountdownRenderProps } from 'react-countdown-now/dist';

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles
  ({});

interface IProps
{}

interface IState
{
    seconds: number;
}

class Counter extends React.Component<IProps & WithStyles<typeof styles>, IState>
{
    constructor(props: IProps & WithStyles<typeof styles>)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state =
        {
            seconds: 60000
        }
    }

    // Random component
    Completionist = () => <span>Time is up!</span>;

    // Renderer callback with condition
    renderer = (props: CountdownRenderProps): JSX.Element =>
    {
        if (props.completed)
        {
            // Render a completed statep
            return this.Completionist();
        }
        else
        {
            // Render a countdown
            return <span>{props.minutes}:{props.seconds}</span>;
        }
    }

    render()
    {
        const css = this.props.classes;
        const seconds = this.state.seconds;

        const Body = () =>
            <Countdown date={Date.now() + seconds} renderer={ this.renderer } />

        return Body();
    }
}

export default withRoot(withStyles(styles)(Counter));
```

What I need in my project is this counter in 4 different pages, that follows each other, with the remained time on the new page.

My idea was to create a singleton, but I failed.
Any help!
thnx

Comment: I ended up addign a static passed time counter and substract it in the state initializer. Probably not the best solution, but fits for my needs  now.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do this. You can move the state higher up to the root element and pass it it down using props to your counter elements. The problem with this approach is that the logic for incrementing the state will then need to be in the root element to, otherwise it will get incremented more depending on how many Counters you have on screen.

React isn't really meant to be a full application framework, it's really just for rendering HTML. If you want to manage application state properly you should be using something like Redux, which interacts very nicely with React and gives you lots of flexibility. More here: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: I am using a custom store, but the problem with that is that needs to be updated every second, and react throws an error for that.

Comment: Another option - use the target time as the prop, calculate the remaining time during render, and use a setInterval to forceUpdate the component every second.